# Python return json to PHP and use json_decode

Tags: php, python

According to this mine question
[Python find value in array by filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52531665/python-find-value-in-array-by-filter/52533228#52533228)

This is what I have done

```
data = {}

for result in results:
    if 'stackoverflow.com' in result['serp_url']:
        data['url'] = result['serp_url']
        data['rank'] = result['serp_rank']
        data['query'] = result['query']
        print(data)
        exit
```

This is PHP code

```
$test = shell_exec("python3 py.py");
var_dump($test);
```

And this is output

```
/home/user/Desktop/pyphp/index.php:4:string '{'url': 'https://stackoverflow.com/', 'rank': 1, 'query': 'stackoverflow'}
{'url': 'https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com', 'rank': 36, 'query': 'stackoverflow'}
' (length=168)
```

When I use `json_decode($test)` I'm getting null as output.

What's the best way to use as json or array output from Python in PHP?

Comment: could You please do `echo $test;`, not `var_dump()`?

Comment: This is output
`{'url': 'https://stackoverflow.com/', 'rank': 1, 'query': 'stackoverflow'} {'url': 'https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com', 'rank': 36, 'query': 'stackoverflow'}` as one string

Comment: That's not valid json, that's your problem. You should wrap it into an array.

Comment: so this is not a correct JSON syntax... you got like 2 objects in one... `{'url': 'https://stackoverflow.com/', 'rank': 1, 'query': 'stackoverflow'} ` and `{'url': 'https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com', 'rank': 36, 'query': 'stackoverflow'}`

Comment: From Python side? How to do that? I tried json.dumps(data) but still not working

Comment: seems that you got some other `print()` in the script, as the part you gave seems to be valid

Comment: i think use `exec()` is better than `shell_exec`
try this `exec('YOUR_COMMAND',$output)` and at last `print_r(output)`

Comment: could you please try `json_decode($test, true)`

Comment: @dogano it won't help :) `json_decode()` fails, doesn't really matter if it returns object or array, as it fails

Comment: @NicolasMarek you can create json string as per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23110383/how-to-dynamically-build-a-json-object-with-python)

Comment: @FlashThunder null means that your JSON string is invalid. Have you validated the syntax?

Comment: I would concentrate on what python returns... it seems that after this function it return some other object

Comment: @dogano but `(...,true)` param only makes it an array from stdClass

Comment: Other reason its Invalid JSON. JSON specifies that you must use DoubleQuotes and not single quotes

Comment: @RiggsFolly you must also ensure that your string is UTF8 encoded

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for comments! According to that, I kind figure out solution.

Python script

```
data = {}
for result in results:
    if 'stackoverflow.com' in result['serp_url']:
        data['url'] = result['serp_url']
        data['rank'] = result['serp_rank']
        data['query'] = result['query']
        print(json.dumps(data))
        exit
```

PHP script

```
exec("python3 py.py", $output);

$test = [];

foreach($output as $key => $out) {
    $test[$key] = json_decode($out, true);
    print_r("Rank: " . $test[$key]['rank'] ." - ". $test[$key]['url']."<br>");
}
```

Output

```
Rank: 1 - https://stackoverflow.com/
Rank: 36 - https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even have to even use Json package of Python. Here is little tweek. In Python and PHP code.

```
# Your py.py Looks Below: 
data = {}
data["aa"] = 100
# You can create any Valid Dictionary
print data
```

and Your Php File will have this code

```
<?php
    $test = shell_exec("python py.py");
    echo json_decode(json_encode($test));
    // $test itself is a json String you even dont need encode/decode
?>
```

And The Result in my Terminal got `{'aa': 100}` Which is Expected and you want.

Now Important Point is that shell_exec command will give you the string which is converted from Dictionary and fortunately, That string itself is a JSON, That why json_decode is returning NULL.

Above both Snippet works fine. Check them.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This will be useful as well!

Comment: Great I hope it should solve your problem. Can you accept as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Python file:

```
import json
import base64

j_data = {
"name": "wick",
"age": 24,
}

jso_en = json.dumps(j_data , indent=4)
#encode with base64
res_arr_bytes = jso_en.encode("ascii")  
base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(res_arr_bytes)
base64_enc = base64_bytes.decode("ascii")
print(base64_enc)
```

PHP file:

```
$command = escapeshellcmd("python3 test.py");
$json_out = shell_exec($command);
$json_data = json_decode(base64_decode($json_out), true);
echo $json_data['name'];
```

output from php:

```
wick
```

Answer (score -1):

The json you're generating is not valid (free objects outside of an array and strings between single quotes).

In your python code you should append your `data` objects to an array as you're creating them. Here's a rough attempt at solving your issue

```
import json

data = [] # use a list to keep your objects

for result in results:
    if 'stackoverflow.com' in result['serp_url']:
        record = {}
        record['url'] = result['serp_url']
        record['rank'] = result['serp_rank']
        record['query'] = result['query']
        data.append(record)
        # exit # <-- this doesn't seem correct, TBH
json.dumps(data)
```

Comment: In my opinion it's not a reason why it returns 2 objects at once... ofc objects won't aggregate, but still the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @FlashThunder IMHO, the problem is that what OP posted is not what they're actually using to get that output (that's why I commented out the `exit`). I'll keep my answer here anyway just in case and I will understand and accept any downvote that comes my way :)

Comment: You may be right, that's why I only posted a comment.

Comment: Thanks for this, but didn't work, since I got null when executed script.