# Extracting JSON to PHP

Tags: python, php, arrays, json

I have this JSON data:

```json
{
    'total': 4744.134525437842,
    'produksiHarian': [14.800870530853988, 15.639301040842536, 16.358413710544085, 16.952318230836113, 17.45055097248538, 17.8754763326927, 18.242760426469818, 18.563566329550866, 18.84608147199738, 19.096480365524762, 19.319535085761938, 19.519012642165947, 19.697941287301326, 19.85879401510806, 20.003618226362324, 20.134129444022808, 20.251780420564497, 20.357813020693253, 20.453297802680865, 20.539164652786695, 20.616226805275556, 20.685199899184028, 20.746717259937547, 20.801342274156227, 20.84957850042934, 20.891877998489687, 20.928648243306515, 20.960257904532423, 20.98704170951842, 21.009304559328097, 21.02732503324213, 21.04135838755367, 21.051639134485804, 21.058383270889877, 21.061790211998733, 21.06204447637534, 21.059317160271767, 21.053767231480556, 21.045542669893685, 21.034781475111366, 21.021612560179374, 21.00615654632769, 20.988526471783015, 20.968828425574475, 20.947162115751837, 20.923621380118846, 20.898294646278586, 20.871265347053306, 20.842612296170422, 20.81241002931908, 20.780729113365243, 20.747636428352394, 20.713195424315565, 20.677466356070354, 20.640506497917034, 20.602370340344187, 20.563109770866646, 20.522774239980293, 20.481410913972358, 20.43906481622342, 20.395778956975676, 20.351594453761813, 20.306550642902003, 20.260685182530857, 20.2140341483766, 20.166632122825597, 20.118512277471417, 20.069706450240275, 20.020245217044497, 19.970157959020252, 19.91947292463175, 19.868217288461143, 19.8164172056869, 19.764097863533138, 19.711283528975187, 19.657997593949958, 19.604262617587615, 19.550100366045164, 19.495531849637345, 19.44057735828815, 19.385256494483215, 19.329588204494947, 19.27359080791663, 19.217282025359857, 19.160679004832186, 19.103798346432747, 19.046656125958414, 18.989267917047492, 18.931648812181788, 18.873813442747196, 18.81577599788325, 18.757550242343445, 18.699149533671857, 18.6405868382421, 18.581874746778492, 18.523025488812625, 18.464050946690364, 18.40496266872333, 18.345771881921006, 18.286489503922823, 18.22712615435876, 18.167692166040553, 18.10819759492825, 18.048652230580856, 17.989065605305793, 17.929447003393125, 17.869805469665625, 17.810149817913633, 17.750488638676536, 17.690830306996318, 17.631182989544868, 17.571554651719957, 17.51195306422644, 17.452385809386776, 17.392860287453175, 17.333383722465378, 17.27396316777987, 17.214605511453826, 17.155317481724854, 17.096105651663066, 17.036976444166896, 16.977936136611227, 16.918990865183517, 16.860146629088725, 16.801409294861866, 16.742784600211646, 16.68427815766247, 16.625895458611, 16.567641876376022, 16.509522670079573, 16.45154298747203, 16.393707868422275, 16.336022247883598, 16.27849095868826, 16.221118734581758, 16.163910212830586, 16.106869936959832, 16.050002359157844, 15.993311842932966, 15.936802665326628, 15.880479019354743, 15.824345016126932, 15.768404686995313, 15.712661985734963, 15.657120790467255, 15.601784905648337, 15.546658063920907, 15.491743927918497, 15.437046092169679, 15.382568084608975, 15.328313368307523, 15.274285343221132, 15.220487347578999, 15.16692265923469, 15.113594497620934, 15.0605060246799, 15.007660346458055, 14.955060514464767, 14.90270952682481, 14.850610329633396, 14.798765818107297, 14.747178837940567, 14.69585218616739, 14.644788612493286, 14.593990820280863, 14.543461467685608, 14.493203168535093, 14.443218493447299, 14.39350997078121, 14.344080087478691, 14.294931290060344, 14.246065985484877, 14.197486542047413, 14.149195290142538, 14.101194523154854, 14.053486498128224, 14.00607343682552, 13.958957526073434, 13.912140918789852, 13.865625734588422, 13.819414060513688, 13.7735079516744, 13.727909431921148, 13.682620494481162, 13.637643102609184, 13.592979190079985, 13.548630662075965, 13.504599395247906, 13.460887238869981, 13.417496014964822, 13.374427519057994, 13.331683520572508, 13.289265763416816, 13.247175966417203, 13.205415823915152, 13.163987006093256, 13.122891159524887, 13.082129907627525, 13.041704851049357, 13.00161756813468, 12.961869615439428, 12.92246252783121, 12.883397819280237, 12.844676983002383, 12.806301491915125, 12.768272798969974, 12.730592337536208, 12.693261521807058, 12.656281747111938, 12.619654390164264, 12.583380809564924, 12.547462346008738, 12.511900322601504, 12.476696045229488, 12.441850802865273, 12.407365867693482, 12.373242495726032, 12.339481926742957, 12.30608538481023, 12.273054078443513, 12.240389200883609, 12.208091930367303, 12.176163430335453, 12.144604849869609, 12.113417323629534, 12.082601972368685, 12.052159902950859, 12.022092208828521, 11.992399969993468, 11.963084253360218, 11.934146112942067, 11.905586590110847, 11.87740671362035, 11.849607500150267, 11.822189954119143, 11.795155068047137, 11.768503822944655, 11.742237188086747, 11.716356121512085, 11.690861570169744, 11.665754469830294, 11.641035745721641, 11.61670631223086, 11.592767073301818, 11.56921892259734, 11.54606274368794, 11.523299410005265, 11.500929785229562, 11.478954723325614, 11.457375068721841, 11.436191656370681, 11.415405312010517, 11.395016852308974, 11.375027084858633, 11.355436808374336, 11.3362468128885, 11.31745787988622, 11.299070782263815, 11.281086284692925, 11.26350514351713, 11.246328107054104, 11.229555915546886, 11.213189301433452, 11.19722898932358, 11.181675696265113, 11.166530131659304, 11.151792997582067, 11.137464988637976, 11.12354679236573, 11.110039089001837, 11.096942551941297, 11.084257847527535, 11.071985635306518, 11.06012656807583, 11.04868129196148, 11.037650446580678, 11.027034665116119, 11.01683457427242, 11.00705079452253, 10.997683940178195, 10.988734619313746, 10.980203434096214, 10.972090980619463, 10.964397849202978, 10.957124624281988, 10.950271884558536, 10.943840203180603, 10.93783014765815, 10.932242279952963, 10.927077156683769, 10.922335329126735, 10.91801734312764, 10.914123739478882, 10.910655053684259, 10.907611816305053, 10.904994552693946, 10.90280378342666, 10.901040024063288, 10.899703785374516, 10.898795573363255, 10.898315889314617, 10.898265229903306, 10.898644087067368, 10.899452948405138, 10.900692296872883],
    'r_squared': 0.9822381604039494,
    'variabel': [152821.1630401214, 55.892346845823056, 23.76556145798208, 26712.22875205879, -0.6822113529338901]
}
```

This is my PHP code :

```
$result = shell_exec('C:\xampp\htdocs\prosold\python\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/xampp/htdocs/prosold/python/main.py ' . escapeshellarg(json_encode($testday)));

        //echo $output;
        //$dataParse = [];
        $dataParse = json_decode(json_encode($result), true);

        echo $dataParse;
```

This is my Python code:

```
ParseData = {}
ParseData['total'] = totalProduksi
ParseData['produksiHarian'] = fittedData
ParseData['r_squared'] = r_square
ParseData['variabel'] = variabel

print(ParseData)
```

and when try to extract total, using this code:

```
$dataParse = json_decode(json_encode($result), true);

echo $dataParse['total'];
```

I get an error:

> illegal string offset

But, when I try do this:

```
$dataParse = json_decode(json_encode($result), true);

echo $dataParse[0];
echo $dataParse[1];
echo $dataParse[2];
echo $dataParse[3];
```

This is the result:

> {'to

What do I miss?

Comment: Why are you encoding `$result` before you decode it? If you get `$result` as json, you should only decode it. I also don't see any json encoding in python? Does it do that automatically when you print the value (I'm not too familiar with python)?

Comment: i tried not encode it, and it say null, but when i do encode it, the json data is showing.
and i know it in this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52535136/python-return-json-to-php-and-use-json-decode

Comment: i think, i kinda miss in python code when identifying json data.

Comment: If your python outputs json, then all you should do in PHP is: `$data = json_decode($result, true);`. Remove your `json_encode()` and it will decode the stringified json (from python) into a PHP array. Also, you won't be able to echo `$data` since it then will be an array. If you want to see what it looks like, do a `var_dump($data);`

Comment: how do i double quote that in python? any reference i can read?

Comment: I'm sure there are many many guides about generating valid json in python. Do some research and try some out. You can also test the ouput with some json validator (just google it, there are plenty free online tools that can help you with that)

Comment: thankyou guys.. i appreciate it
 sorry if my english so bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That data is JSON-like, but not valid JSON. The keys are wrapped in single quotes, but the JSON standard **requires** double quotes.

To produce valid JSON from a Python object use `json.dumps()`

For example:

```
import json

dictionary = {'a':34, 'b':61, 'c':82}
jsonString = json.dumps(dictionary, indent=4)
print(jsonString)
```

Which gives:

```
{
    "a": 34,
    "b": 61,
    "c": 82
}
```

In that form PHP should be able to read your data and decode it with `json_decode()`

Comment: Thank you! smooth like butter. i hope when u die, you're in heaven